# Need to change the date format of an entire column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to change the date format for an existing column in the table

select to_date(dob, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as myDate;

This is to select the date while displaying. I need to change the existing column like update it completely

Comment: Dates don't have "a format". If you store your dates in a `text` (or `varchar`) column, then that's a really bad idea. `to_date()` does **not** "format" a date, it converts a string value to a `date` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update [table name] set [col name] = to_date([col name], 'dd/mm/yyyy')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the value as a string, I would recommend using the standard format YYYY-MM-DD and not depending on what a conversion routine returns:

```
update [table name]
     set [col name] = to_char(to_date([col name], 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```